# Arrange icons in full-height container

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange several icons inside a container with the full height of the site (not viewport).

At the moment I only get the height of the viewport with the following code:

```css
.full-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    /* for example */
    width: 100%;
    background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="full-container"></div>
```

Is there a way to get the height of the whole site?

Here is an example of my idea:

[image]

The white area is the visible screen in the browser. The grey area is the rest of the side. I want a DIV with the full height of the page (yellow area).

Comment: Can you share a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: see my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with creating a div 100% is that is only cover the area that is left from the elements where that div is located in. Normally with position absolute this shouldn't be needed but have u tried this:

```
/* CSS */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Another thing I have to ask you if you are using box-sizing. That might be the cause of the issue.

Still I wonder what you are trying to achieve:

```css
body {background-color: red;}
main {
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main><p>test</p></main>
</body>
```

Edite: Seems to be pretty buggy what you are trying todo. The 100% doesn't really seem to support it and just return the value of the pagewidth.